# an error occurred by CameraX.bindToLifecycle()

Tags: android, android-camerax

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported surface combination
>   is found for camera device - Id : 0.  May be attempting to bind too
>   many use cases.

why the `bindToLifecycle()` only choose  `imageCapture` or `videoCapture`?

```
 CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, mPreview, imageCapture,videoCapture)
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue or maybe did you figure out a workaround? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 6):

You are binding more UseCases than your device's camera supports. Not all devices can support two ImageAnalyzers.

Try reducing your analyzers,

```
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, mPreview, imageCapture or videoCapture)
```

I have tested with many devices, so far, among the devices that I tested, only Google Pixel 1 works with three analyzers.

To suggest a hack, remove imageCapture analyzer, try to get images from preview for imageCapture and use videoCapture.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error while popping fragment with camera view from backstack, 
I fixed it by unbinding all analysers when view exits.

```
CameraX.unbindAll()
```

[As suggested here.](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#lifecycles)

Comment: This works but it refreshes the screen. How to avoid that ?

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to bind **Preview** with **VideoCapture**, and **Preview** with **ImageCapture** separately. Binding **Preview**, **ImageCapture** and **VideoCapture** appears to be an issue on a few devices currently. When switching between the two be careful to **unbindAll** first.

This may be because the **VideoCapture** UseCase is not officially supported yet, as of 1.0.0-Beta10.

```
fun startVideoCapture() {
        ...
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                                lifecycleOwner,
                                cameraSelected,
                                previewUseCase,
                                videoCaptureUseCase
                            )
                }
fun startImageCapture() {
        ...
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                                lifecycleOwner,
                                cameraSelected,
                                previewUseCase,
                                imageCaptureUseCase
                            )
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `videoCapture` usecase right now.

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture#combine-use-cases), the available usecases are preview, analysis & image capture (and their combinations).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I tried to create imageCapture, videoCapture, mPreview or the analyzer with different settings between each other.

Try to set in the builder setting the same parameters, e.g. if you want:

```
setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.BACK)
```

Set in all the setting builders the same. This can fix your error but still, I don't know if the library support this feature jet.

Comment: ImageCaptureConfig imgCConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).setLensFacing( CameraX.LensFacing.BACK).build();

Answer (score 0):

As Ye Min Htut pointed out, consider fewer UseCases. For me this was sufficient:

```kotlin
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner, cameraSelector)
```

I hope it can help someone out there =)