# Android CameraX - face detection while recording video

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I'm using the new library CameraX with Firebase ML Kit in Android and detecting faces every frame the device can.

So I set CameraX like that:

```
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture, faceDetectAnalyzer)
```

All working flowless, now, while I'm doing that, I want to record a video.

**So basically I want to to detect faces while recording a video**.

I tried:

```
CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture, faceDetectAnalyzer, videoCapture)
```

But I'm getting an error saying that there are too many parameters so I guess that's not the right way.

I know that this library still in alpha but I guess there is a way to do that.

Even if there is not jet, what's another way to implement face detection while recording a video with Firebase ML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [an error occurred by CameraX.bindToLifecycle()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126429/an-error-occurred-by-camerax-bindtolifecycle)

Comment: No is not, that's a different error, that come in different circumstances, I'll answer his question.
Also my question is about the implementation not just about the error.

Comment: try using the Media Projection API and record the screen instead if you want to try it out... just a suggestion personally I have not used the ML kit

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054647/can-i-record-video-with-camerax-android-jetpack

Comment: @GMX, did find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use CameraX a lot, but I'm usually working with Camera 2 API and Firebase ML Kit.

For use both API together, you should get the `Image` callbacks from your Preview Size `ImageReader`. On that callback you can use that Images to create a `FirebaseVisionFace` through the API and do whatever you want with it. 
Using Kotlin and Coroutines it should look like these:

```
 private val options: FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
    .setContourMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CONTOURS)
    .build()

val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionFaceDetector(options)

suspend fun processImage(image: Image): FirebaseVisionFace {
    val metadata = FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
        .setWidth(image.width) // 480x360 is typically sufficient for image recognition
        .setHeight(image.height)
        .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
        .build()

    val visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(image)
    val firebaseVisionFace = detector.detectInImage(visionImage).await()

    return firebaseVisionFace
}
```

If you want to use the `await` method for Coroutine support you can give a loot to https://github.com/FrangSierra/Firebase-Coroutines-Android

Comment: I'm already doing this and using both API together (image capture and Face Detection) and is working fine.
The question is, on top of that can I record a video?

Comment: I dont know about cameraX but API 2 doesn't allow you to do FaceRecognition with Firebase because the preview is not throwing 'Image' objects, you could do it with the preview image reader or maybe a low quality one running together with the videoSession(like you usually do for take snapshots)

Comment: I don't know too but I'm sure is possible to record video while detecting faces, I saw apps doing it and they are using Firebase.

Comment: My guess is that they are doing it not with camera x but with camera2 somehow

Comment: any clue on this?